# Change Toolbar with change of Fragment like instagram app

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewpager, instagram

I am trying to implement exactly like Instagram app navigation system, in which there is a fixed bottom bar with which user can navigate between screens by clicking icons in bottom bar and accordingly toolbar title and toolbar back navigation should get changed.

I made lots of research on this and found few solution but none of them is perfect.

1. similar question:-
   [Implementing Instagram like in-app navigation system on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036778/implementing-instagram-like-in-app-navigation-system-on-android)
2. Using ViewPager :- Currently i am following this pattern, making multiple fragment stack inside each ViewPager Tab

https://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Instagram like in-app navigation system on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036778/implementing-instagram-like-in-app-navigation-system-on-android)

Comment: Yeah some how but that question is not been answered yet properly.

Comment: once, you have sufficient points, you can open a bounty on that question

Comment: I am able to implement fragment navigation with viewpager but i am unable to change toolbar title and back button of toolbar when user backpress

Comment: @nishanttanwar I had a task to create instagram-like navigation, here's you hopefully can find some details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367309/retain-getchildfragmentmanager-navigation-stack-after-removing-and-re-adding-fra

Comment: @KonstantinLoginov I have explored your code it looks fine but i am unable to get full clarification about your custom "FragmentMetaData" class can you give me an example ?

Comment: @NishantTanwar posted `FragmentMetaData` class as an answer, as it's impossible to fit it into the comment. I hope, it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a task to create instagram-like navigation, here's you hopefully can find some details: [Retain getChildFragmentManager navigation stack after removing and re-adding fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367309/retain-getchildfragmentmanager-navigation-stack-after-removing-and-re-adding-fra)

`FragmentMetaData` class for me looked like:

```
public class FragmentMetaData {
    public final String className;
    public final Bundle fragmentBundle;

    public FragmentMetaData(final String className, final Bundle fragmentBundle) {
        this.className = className;
        this.fragmentBundle = fragmentBundle;
    }
}
```

I hope, it helps

Comment: This is working like instagram but whenever i switch between tabs it always recreates the fragment instead of resuming it. do you know the workaround with this ?

Comment: @NishantTanwar well, once you replace fragments in the container - they are gonna be recreated. That's by fragments' design. You can try to add all of them and once you need to change tab - do .show() / .hide(). But watch out the memory usage, as it might lead to OutOfMemmory Exceptions.